# Distinta dpi en x respecto a la de y. javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de representar un rectángulo de 3x2 en el canvas, dibujado en píxeles mediante javascript. Me interesa sobre todo que conserve la relación, en la medida de los posible, en el papel, no en la pantalla. Al imprimir este rectángulo a pdf, y después a papel, el eje Y se elonga y la relación para mi ordenador, medida con una regla, pasa a ser 4x3. 
He instalado una libreria ([res](https://www.npmjs.com/package/res)) con la que puedo obtener la dppx,dpi y dpcm.
Sn embargo no veo como puedo diferenciar entre la dpi de x y de y (si es que son distintas), y no se me ocurre otra manera de calcular la elongación (3/2 / 4/3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un canvas tiene dos tamaños, el interno y el externo: el interno indica los pixels con los que vas a trabajar en los cálculos, el externo indica los píxeles del elemento canvas en el HTML:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);


var canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas2');
var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

ctx2.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx2.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);

console.log(`Tamaño 'externo': (${canvas.scrollWidth},${canvas.scrollHeight})`);
console.log(`Tamaño 'interno': (${canvas.width},${canvas.height})`);
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: gray;
  float:left;
}

#canvas {
   width: 100px;
   height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="150" height="140" id="canvas"></canvas>

<canvas width="200" height="200" id="canvas2"></canvas>
```

Como puedes ver, en ambos "canvas" se dibuja un cuadrado de 90*90, pero el primero está totalmente deformado. Puedes calcular el ratio de deformación usando ambas medidas, la externa y la interna, y por tanto calcular el tamaño "visible" del cuadrado en cualquier eje.

Por otro lado, los pixels usados por CSS y los pixels reales de tu pantalla pueden no coincidir por el tema de la densidad de pixeles: En un monitor de 24 pulgadas con una resolución de 1920*1080, un pixel puede ser medio milímetro, mientras que en un móvil puede ser que haya 15 píxeles por milímetro.

Por tanto es recomendable que el tamaño "interno" del canvas sea igual al tamaño externo (asumiendo que quieres mantener las proporciones) multiplicado por la propiedad `window.devicePixelRatio`, para que lo que muestres en el canvas se vea lo mejor posible. Esto no da un resultado exacto, porque la mayoría de móviles te dan un valor de 2 o 3 (suele ser un valor entero) cuando quizá lo correcto sería algo como 2.56 o un valor similar.

[Por definición](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#absolute-lengths), un "pixel CSS" tiene un tamaño tal que 96px = 1in (una pulgada, 25.4 mm).

Por último, te recuerdo que si vas a imprimir desde el navegador, los CSS de pantalla no tienen que ser los mismo que los de la impresora: usando `@media print` en tus estilos puedes definir una presentación para la impresión distinta a la de la pantalla, definiendo el tamaño de tu imagen para ajustarla a tu gusto.

Comment: Extremadamente útil.ty

Comment: @Java_learner Si esta respuesta te sirve, por favor márcala como aceptada, para no dejar la pregunta como "sin respuesta". Te pediría que lo hagas con todas las preguntas que hagas y que tengan una respuesta que te haya ayudado (veo en tu historial que no lo has hecho hasta ahora).

Comment: No lo sabía, ya lo he hecho, gracias. En efecto ya me parecía ilógico que tuviese distinta dpi. Me he hecho un lío con el canvas y estaba redimensionandolo dos veces. Muy buena la explicación.